# Can I limit bandwidth for certain IP address, subnet or VLAN on Cisco 881?

Tags: networking, cisco, bandwidth, bandwidth-control

I have a router with several workstations running on the switched ports. I need to limit their WAN bandwidth. I tried to use `rate-limit` on `Vlan1`, but it looks like it had no effect. What is the easiest way to achieve this? I am not very good at cisco configuration.

Comment: Add information about image which used on your router(it's looks like this example: c880data-universalk9-mz.150-1.M7) 

Also better to ask this kind of questions on  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @IvanGurzhiy c800-universalk9-mz.SPA.154-3.M.bin I thought about it, but I was afraid that my question was too simple for networkengineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
policy-map POLICEALL
 class class-default
   police rate 256k

interface Vlan1
 service-policy input POLICEALL
 service-policy output POLICEALL
```

[source](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/57424/55741)